# Chrome hotkey to move horizontal bar to the very right

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

Whenever I open a small window in Chrome that has a horizontal bar I would like to have a keyboard shortcut to move that bar to the very right.
How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by horizontal bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#If WinActive("ahk_exe Chrome.exe")

F2::
WinGetPos,,, Width, Height, A
w := Width-50
h := Height-15
ControlClick, x%w% y%h%, A
return

#If
```

Comment: what about the vertical bar?

Comment: To move down the vertical bar you can use WheelDown, PgDown or ^End (to get to the bottom of the page)

Comment: I know that already but at my keyboard is very complicated to do that. For that reason I'm asking here. thanks

Comment: F1:: Send ^{End}